# change input background color if its empty

Tags: javascript, html, input, background-color

my problem is that I want to make the background of my inputs red when I leave empty after clicking on it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="name">
<label>Name<sup></sup></label> <br>
    <input id="first" style="font-size:11pt;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name" onChange='emptyField("first")'/>
    <input id="last" style="font-size:11pt;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Last Name" onChange='emptyField("last")'/> 
</div>
```

Here is my javascript program:

```
function emptyField(x) {
var field = document.getElementById(x);

if(field !== ""){
    field.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
else {
    field.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}}
```

Just to mention, I've just started to learn HTML, CSS, JS and PHP. So hopefully it's not too complicated for me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example. Notice the use of the `focusout` event rather than `change`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('focusout', setInputBackground)
});

function setInputBackground() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = !!this.value ? "white" : "red";
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
  <label>Name<sup></sup></label> <br>
  <input id="firstname" style="font-size:11pt;" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
  <input id="lastname" style="font-size:11pt;" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use onblur() event to capture the focus out of the input box and to check the field value.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="name">
<label>Name<sup></sup></label> <br>
    <input id="first" style="font-size:11pt;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name" onblur='emptyField("first")'/>
    <input id="last" style="font-size:11pt;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Last Name" onblur='emptyField("last")'/> 
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

To get the field value, you have write `field.value` instead of just `field`,

```
function emptyField(x) {
    var field = document.getElementById(x);
    
    if(field.value !== ""){
        field.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    else {
        field.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }}
```